# Apache Config - Exclude Subdirectories

Tags: apache, configuration, subdirectory

Is there a way to apply a rule to a single directory and not its subdirectories without using .htaccess files?  I want /var/www/html to order by the Date desc.  However, in the subdirectories, I don't want this rule applied.

Right now, I have IndexOrderDefault Descending Date within the /var/www/html Directory tag.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For users who encounter this problem: See https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=49809 (Apache bug 49809). $ is not recognized by Apache as an end of line anchor for some inexplicable reason.

Comment: Great followup.  I wish I had the time to look into it a while back.  I remember banging my head against the wall on this one!

Answer (score 4):

You can use the DirectoryMatch directive to match that directory (and only that directory) exactly:

```
<DirectoryMatch "^/www/var/html$">
    IndexOrderDefault Descending Date
</DirectoryMatch>
```

It uses regular expressions to match the directory path. See http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/core.html#directorymatch for more info.

Comment: Yeah, everything I've read points to this being the best way to do it.  For some reason my apache on Fedora 8 seems to be ignoring the end of line anchor in the regular expression.  I'll try it on my Centos box when I get a chance, and if it works, I'll give you the credit.

Answer (score 1):

Rich Leland’s answer doesn’t work for me under Apache 2.4.43.  What does work is this:

```
<DirectoryMatch '^/var/www/html/?$'>
    IndexOrderDefault Descending Date
    </DirectoryMatch>
```

The difference is the `/?$`, which allows for requests that ‘may or may not end in a trailing slash’.  See `<DirectoryMatch>` in the 2.4 manual.

Beware though, the above works only for directives such as `IndexOrderDefault` that apply exclusively to directory requests.  (I think the manual is unclear on this point.)  If you want to add a directive that applies to requests for regular files *contained* in the directory, then you need something like this:

```
<DirectoryMatch '^/var/www/html(?:/[^/]*)?$'>
    IndexOrderDefault Descending Date
    SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
    </DirectoryMatch>
```

Note that works only if all subdirectory requests are terminated with a slash, which effectively they are when `<DirectorySlash>` is left at its default setting.

And all of this requires Apache version 2.3.9 or later.  “Prior to 2.3.9, [`<DirectoryMatch>`] implicitly applied to sub-directories (like `<Directory>`) and could not match the end of line symbol (`$`).”

Comment: "_that works only if all subdirectory requests are terminated with a slash_" Well, what happens if subdirectory requests are _not_ terminated with a slash? Is it that the directives don't apply to anything at all? Or that they do indeed apply to the desired files, but also apply to subdirctories and their files?

Comment: Also, it seems that your regular expression is built to match against a full file path. I would have expected that when a file is requested, Apache itself parses out the directory part of the path, and uses this to match against `DirectoryMatch` arguments. No?

Comment: Re my last comment... I've done a little testing (Apache 2.4.46), and it seems like your approach is correct - if directives are to apply to files inside the directory, then the argument to the `DirectoryMatch` directive needs to match the full file path, including file name. Odd, IMHO. That's obviously not how the `Directory` directive works.